# R - How to display values of a ordered factor on axis with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to display the values of an ordered factor on a barplot with `ggplot2` (ideally, otherwise with standard plot).

I have an ordered factor like this one:

> "How are you satisfied with the exercises :"
>   - absolutely not satisfied => value 1
>   - not satisfied => value 2
>   - satisfied => value 3
>   - very satisfied => value 4

I want to plot a barplot with the mean and the values "absolutely not satisfied" -> "very satisfied" on the axis instead 1 -> 4.

Is it possible to do that with `ggplot2`? In my point of view, the main difficulty is to plot the mean of the factor and not a distribution of values (actually my plot is made with a transformation of the ordered factor to an integer).

Here is the result of dput on my dataset.

```
structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("pas du tout satisfait", "plutôt pas satisfait", 
"plutôt satisfait", "très satisfait"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor"))
```

And here is the example of barplot (without the values on the axis...):

[image: example]

The code is the following.

```
Toto <- structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("pas du tout satisfait", "plutôt pas satisfait", 
              "plutôt satisfait", "très satisfait"), class = c("ordered","factor"))

TotoNumeric <- as.data.frame(as.integer(Toto))

DataForGggplot2 <- as.data.frame(round(sapply(X = TotoNumeric, FUN = "mean", na.rm = TRUE), 1))
colnames(DataForGggplot2) <- "Donnees"
DataForGggplot2$Etiquette <- "the exercises"

Graphe <- ggplot(data = DataForGggplot2, aes(x = Etiquette, y = Donnees)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 4))
  coord_flip()

print(Graphe)
```

I can give you further details if my request is not clear.

Thanks

Comment: The x axis in my example (the axis with the values, not the label of the question).

Comment: try using `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 4), labels = c("", levels(Toto)))` instead

Comment: Thank you ! Simple finally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option called `labels` in `scale_y_continuous` you can use for this.

For this example I assume that the factor you want to use is `Toto`. Since you set the limits of 0 - 4 (i.e. length = 5) but there are only 4 levels of `Toto`, I added `NA` for the value of 0. You also could set the limits as 0 - 3 or 1 - 4 without needing to add the `NA` level.

```
library(ggplot2)

Toto <- structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("pas du tout satisfait", "plutôt pas satisfait", 
              "plutôt satisfait", "très satisfait"), class = c("ordered","factor"))

TotoNumeric <- as.data.frame(as.integer(Toto))

DataForGggplot2 <- as.data.frame(round(sapply(X = TotoNumeric, FUN = "mean", na.rm = TRUE), 1))
colnames(DataForGggplot2) <- "Donnees"
DataForGggplot2$Etiquette <- "the exercises"

Graphe <- ggplot(data = DataForGggplot2, aes(x = Etiquette, y = Donnees)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Toto",  labels = c("NA", levels(Toto)),limits = c(0, 4))

coord_flip()

print(Graphe)
```

[image]

For more details and examples, [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-ticks-a-guide-to-customize-tick-marks-and-labels) is a great resource.

Comment: Thank you. I don't need the "NA" value therefore I try `limits = c(0,3)` who works but `limits = c(1,4)` doesn't.

Comment: An other remark : it seems that `limits =` is mandatory. When I try to remove, i have an error _Error in f(..., self = self) : Breaks and labels are different lengths_. Is it possible to avoid the use of `limits =` to simplify the code ?

Comment: You're welcome. `limits = c(1, 4)` will also work, but you just have to set the `breaks` accordingly.  `limits` is required but it can be set to `NA`  to refer to the existing minimum or maximum. I would not recommend it though; I gave it a try just now and it had bad results. If you want to be programmatic then you could set the limits to functions of your data, e.g. `limits=c(1, max(df$y)`.  If your question is answered please click the green checkmark to direct future readers to the answer.